# On sign up through devise rails if user email already signed up or exist then just send an email to the given address to sign in to your account?

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I've no idea that where i have to add code or where inside devise i have to make changes to get the results?

Comment: can anybody help me out with this????

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom devise controllers (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) and add the desired behaviour by modifying RegistrationsController::create

```
def create
  if User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).present?
    # do something
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom device controller check for the user email is present already in DB or not,
If the user is present then get the email address of the user and pass the email_id as well login link to the custom mailer.